# Standby button won't work

Tags: windows-xp, standby

I had to restore my Dell 1501 with my XP restore disc made with the laptop but I lost my standby button and want to get it back.

It used to go into standby but now when I close the lid it stays on unless I push the power button.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing the [Dell QuickSet](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/Product/inspiron-1501?driverId=J7H4J&osCode=ww1&fileId=2731098642) driver/application from your laptop.  Install it, and everything should work as it used to.

Comment: Thanks I have downloaded it but it will let me set it to go into standby but still stays on when the lid is down.

Comment: Very strange ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Control Panel and bring up the Power Options (or right click on the desktop, go to Properties, click the screen saver tab and then the Power button).
[image]

Click the Advanced Tab.  Change what your computer does when you close the lid.
[image]

Hit Apply, then Ok.  You should be good to go.

Images courtesy of [Computerhint.com](http://www.computerhint.com/2010/04/setting-windows-xp-power-options-how-to.html)

Comment: Sorry I have tried that and when I open the advanced it only shows 2 options, close lid - do nothing, power - shut down, ask or do nothing.

Comment: the standby button is still shown when I shut down but not red, it's grey and not distinct.

Comment: Then most likely, as @Keltari has pointed out, you have not installed all the Dell drivers for your model laptop.  Dell typically ships all their drivers on a separate disc.  There isn't a restore disc per se.  There is a copy of Windows, and a drivers disc.

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled with a restore disc created from the same laptop and I have used the drivers disc that came with it but alas it still doesn't show my stanby button. Perplexing!!